# Why is my XSLT 1.0 template not called every time?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0

Duplicate connections should be filtered out, so if Destination and LineShortName's values exist several times only the first occurence should be displayed.

XML Data:

```
<Stop>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>10</LineName>
        <LineShortName>10</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
        <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T10:52:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>2/12</LineName>
        <LineShortName>2/12</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <Destination>WALLERSHEIM</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T10:47:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>
    </Connection>
        <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>1</LineName>
        <LineShortName>1</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <Destination>GOLDGRUBE</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:16:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>1</LineName>
        <LineShortName>1</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <Destination>ALTSTADT</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T10:44:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>9</LineName>
        <LineShortName>9</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>9</LineNumber>
        <Destination>KO-ZENTRUM</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:24:00</ScheduledDepartureTime
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>2/12</LineName>
        <LineShortName>2/12</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <Destination>WALLERSHEIM</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:17:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>8</LineName>
        <LineShortName>8</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>8</LineNumber>
        <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:25:00</ScheduledDepartureTime
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>3/13</LineName>
        <LineShortName>3/13</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
        <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:08:00</ScheduledDepartureTime
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>1</LineName>
        <LineShortName>1</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <Destination>ALTSTADT</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:14:00</ScheduledDepartureTime
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>20</LineName>
        <LineShortName>20</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
        <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:24:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>2/12</LineName>
        <LineShortName>2/12</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <Destination>NEUENDORF</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:32:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <ConnectionType>ProtectedConnection</ConnectionType>
        <LineName>10</LineName>
        <LineShortName>10</LineShortName>
        <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
        <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>
        <ConnectionState>ConnectionOK</ConnectionState>
        <VehicleTypeRef>7</VehicleTypeRef>
        <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:22:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>
    </Connection>
</Stop>
```

Expected output (just pure text):

```
LineShortName: 10  Destination: HAUPTBAHNHOF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T10:52:00
LineShortName: 2/12  Destination: WALLERSHEIM  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T10:47:00
LineShortName: 1  Destination: GOLDGRUBE  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:16:00
LineShortName: 1  Destination: ALTSTADT  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T10:44:00
LineShortName: 9  Destination: KO-ZENTRUM  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:24:00
LineShortName: 8  Destination: HAUPTBAHNHOF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:25:00
LineShortName: 3/13 Destination: HAUPTBAHNHOF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:08:00
LineShortName: 20  Destination: HAUPTBAHNHOF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:24:00
LineShortName: 2/12 Destination: NEUENDORF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:32:00
```

template:

```
<xsl:key name="unique-connections" match="Connection" use="concat(Destination, '|', LineShortName)"/>

<xsl:template match="Connection[generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique-connections', concat(Destination, '|', LineShortName)))]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>LineShortName: </xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="LineShortName"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Destination: </xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="Destination"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ScheduledDepartureTime: </xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="ScheduledDepartureTime"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <!--
        <xsl:for-each select="key('unique-connections', concat(Destination, '|', LineShortName))">
            <xsl:text>VehicleTypeRef: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="VehicleTypeRef"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The template is called by another template, which is dealing with the Stops:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Connection">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The actual output:

```
ProtectedConnection101010HAUPTBAHNHOFConnectionOK72017-11-07T10:52:00

LineShortName: 2/12  Destination: WALLERSHEIM  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T10:47:00  

ProtectedConnection111GOLDGRUBEConnectionOK72017-11-07T11:16:00

LineShortName: 1  Destination: ALTSTADT  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T10:44:00  

ProtectedConnection999KO-ZENTRUMConnectionOK72017-11-07T11:24:00ProtectedConnection2/122/122WALLERSHEIMConnectionOK72017-11-07T11:17:00

LineShortName: 8  Destination: HAUPTBAHNHOF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:25:00

LineShortName: 3/13  Destination: HAUPTBAHNHOF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:08:00  

ProtectedConnection111ALTSTADTConnectionOK72017-11-07T11:14:00

LineShortName: 20  Destination: HAUPTBAHNHOF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:24:00  

LineShortName: 2/12  Destination: NEUENDORF  ScheduledDepartureTime: 2017-11-07T11:32:00

ProtectedConnection101010HAUPTBAHNHOFConnectionOK72017-11-07T11:22:00
```

I assume that the template is not matched every time, but why?
For some sets of connections it works perfectly but fails every time with these specific connections.

I have a strong feeling that it would be better to call the template only once with the parent node of the connections but I cannot wrap my head around a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to process all `Connection` elements with your `xsl:apply-templates` but not output anything for the duplicates. Then don't process all of them but use `<xsl:apply-templates select="Connection[generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique-connections', concat(Destination, '|', LineShortName)))]"/>` or make sure if you process all that the ones you don't want to output anything:

```
<xsl:template match="Connection[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique-connections', concat(Destination, '|', LineShortName))))]"/>
```

Otherwise the default templates kick in and spew out any text data.

Online sample http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/6qM2e26 with the empty template for the duplicates outputs

```
<Stop>
    <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>10</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T10:52:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>
    <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>2/12</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>WALLERSHEIM</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T10:47:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>
        <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>1</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>GOLDGRUBE</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:16:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>
    <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>1</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>ALTSTADT</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T10:44:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>
    <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>9</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>KO-ZENTRUM</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:24:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>

    <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>8</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:25:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>
    <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>3/13</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:08:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>

    <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>20</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>HAUPTBAHNHOF</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:24:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>
    <Connection>

LineShortName: <LineShortName>2/12</LineShortName>  Destination: <Destination>NEUENDORF</Destination>  ScheduledDepartureTime: <ScheduledDepartureTime>2017-11-07T11:32:00</ScheduledDepartureTime>  

</Connection>

</Stop>
```

Too much data for me to check by hand but if the key is set up properly I don't see how it could fail.

Comment: I tested both of your suggestions.
- When I change the call I only get the lines which were right in the beginning but the other lines which were not processed by the template are still missing. (line 1, 3, 5, 8, 11 still missing)
- When I change the template match line different lines are missing and duplicates are displayed

Comment: I have added one approach and the result I get, and the other is at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/948Fn58.

Comment: Thank you very much. I deleted almost everything out of my XSL file and edited my XML input file and it seems that there is another issue. If I delete all other stops out of the XML file it works perfectly, so now I have to figure out why stepping through the stops and calling the template goes wrong.

Comment: So you have several `Stop` elements with `Connection` elements? Do you want to eliminate duplicate `Connection`s in the whole document or only inside a `Stop` parent? In the latter case you need to include the `generate-id(..)` in your key definition and computations `<xsl:key name="unique-connections" match="Connection" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', Destination, '|', LineShortName)"/>` to make sure the duplicates are only identified inside a `Stop` element (or any parent element).

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="Stop">`
    `<xsl:if test="Id = $globalStopId">`
`<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>`
`</xsl:if>` 
`</xsl:for-each>`

This is the call which fails.
I guess there is an easier way to just hand over one specific `Stop` element with all childs to the template.

Comment: I replaced the `<xsl:for-each>` block with `<xsl:apply-templates select="Trip/Stop[Id=$globalStopId]"/>` and this does the trick. But I still encounter the same problems like before.

If I delete all 'inactive' Stops out of the XML file it works perfectly. If I keep them in only half of the Connections are displayed.